# Splitting Address - How to search for multiple criteria in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I'm trying to split an address: Say

```
123 99th Pl SE 999
123 99th Pl NE 999
123 99th Pl SW 999
123 99th Pl NW 999
```

I need:

```
123 99th Pl SE
123 99th Pl NE

without the number at the end.
```

I used:

`LEFT(D3,FIND("SE",D3)+1)`   which works.

But is it possible to use multiple criteria for the FIND function? So it looks for one of SE, NE, SW, NW?

I tried `LEFT(D3, FIND({"SE","NE","SW","NW"},D3)+1)` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close.  The problem is you want to find the first occurrence and when it is not found it returns an Error.

Use this array formula:

```
=LEFT(D3, MIN(FIND({"SE","NE","SW","NW"},D3 & "SENESWNW"))+1)
```

being and array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: Perfect - thank you! What is the value for SENESWNW?

Comment: As I stated we need to make sure the value that is being searched can be found so it does not return an error.  The Find will iterate and test each individually, if that individual is not found it will error the whole formula, so we amend the string to have all the possibilities at the end and find the first. @J.Doe

Answer (score 2):

This formula would work for all options, (strips of the last portion)

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("$",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","$",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")))))
```

[image]

Comment: One note, this will split on the last `" "` if there is more than one or no "word" after the desired end then this will only remove the last, even if it is the `"SE","NE","SW","NW"`, but if it always has one "word" after it would work superbly.

Comment: @ScottCraner ah yes, you are right!! But according to the question, there is supposed to be a number always at the end. Hoping so

Comment: That is why I upvoted but left it as a note.  It could be the better method.

Comment: Thank you!! There is actually a possibility that there is no number at the end. I should've mentioned that too.

Comment: Then you should probably use @ScottCraner 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove last three digits, you can use below formula.

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-3)
```

Comment: The OP has stated in comments that the numbers are not always there, so this will not work.